# Probability of conditional Wiener process

Tags: self-study, stochastic-processes

lets assume that we have $W_t$ - Wiener Process.
What will be probability

$$P[W_4-W_2>1|W_3=0.5]$$

I know that if instead of $W_3$ we would have $W_2$ then it would be independent, and

$$P[W_4-W_2\ge1|W_2=0.5]=P[W_4-W_2\ge 1]=1-\Phi(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})$$

but when we have $W_3$, I assume we should do the following:

\begin{align}
P[W_4-W_2\ge1|W_3=0.5] &= P[W_4-W_3+W_3-W_2\ge1|W_3-W_0=0.5]  \\
 &= P[W_4-W_3+W_3-W_2\ge1|W_3-W_2+W_2-W_0=0.5]  \\
 &= P[W_4-W_3+W_3-W_2\ge1|W_3-W_2=0.5-(W_2-W_0)]  \\
 &= P[W_4-W_3-(W_2-W_0)\ge0.5]  \\
 &= ...?
\end{align}

I am not sure about the last step.

And then we get that $W_4-W_3 \sim N(0,1)$ and $W_2-W_0\sim N(0,2)$. So $P[W_4-W_2\ge1|W_3=0.5]=1-\Phi(\frac{1}{2\sqrt{3}})$. Am I correct?

Comment: **Hint:** You have to consider the _joint_ distribution of $W_4-W_3$ and $W_2-W_3$ given $W_3$.

Comment: So because $W_4-W3$ is indipendent from other two it will be distributed as $N(0,1)$ and $W_3-W_2|W_3$ will be $N(W_3,2)$ ?

Comment: 1. $W_4-W_3$ and $W_3-W_2$ are indeed independent. 2. But $W_3-W_2|W_3$ is not distributed as a $N(W_3,2)$ variate.

Comment: this harder then I thought. ok so $W_3|W_3$ is $W_3$ and $W_2|W_3=x$ according to: http://www.math.unl.edu/~sdunbar1/MathematicalFinance/Lessons/BrownianMotion/Definition/definition.pdf
will be $N(x2/3,2/3(3-2))$, so $W_3-W_2|W_3=x\sim N(x/3,2/3)$